# Save the neo4j graph in the browser as an image

Tags: python, graph, neo4j

When we run some query on neo4j browser, we get the result in many forms such as table, text, graph etc. I see an option to save the graph as a PNG image in the browser. But I don't want to manually run the query on the browser and then download the image.

Is there a programmatic way to do this? I am using python for my project. Can somebody suggest some other way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can render you graph to the dot language and use graphviz for rendering.

I have a project here that does it.

https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-graphviz